# Javascript: send Skype text message

Tags: skype, skype4com

According to this Skype developer page:
https://dev.skype.com/skype-uri/skype-uri-tutorial-webpages
it seems that I can initiate a Skype chat dialog from my web page.

But I want to directly send a text message from my web page Javascript to an already-open Skype chat dialog.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

Such feature is available only for desktop Skype API and not exposed to a web browser.

Comment: I'm using Skype on desktop, does that help?

Comment: Your JavaScript on the web page and Skype cannot communicate, so not it's not possible.

Comment: If there is a way to inject text into Skype dialog (from the OS), then I may use some non-standard ways for Javascript to communicate with the OS, such as via clipboard.